# Create an intermediate calculated column or expand the definition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, calculated-columns

Is there material difference (based on how Spark is implemented) between:

```
tempColumn = commonColumnExpression

df = (
   df.withColumn('tempColumn', tempColumn)
   df.withColumn('newColumn1', col('existingColumn') + col('tempColumn')
   df.withColumn('newColumn2', col('existingColumn') - col('tempColumn')
)
```

and

```
tempColumnDef = commonColumnExpression

df = (
   df.withColumn('tempColumn', tempColumn)
   df.withColumn('newColumn1', col('existingColumn') + tempColumnDef)
   df.withColumn('newColumn2', col('existingColumn') - tempColumnDef)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no difference. You can check it through `df.explain()`. [`explain`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain) shows you what was the actual sequence of steps Spark decided to take (physical plan) after interpreting your code. In your case, we can see that both physical plans are identical (internal column IDs don't matter).

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

df = spark.createDataFrame([(5,),], ['existingColumn'])

commonColumnExpression = lit(2)

tempColumn = commonColumnExpression
df1 = (
   df.withColumn('tempColumn', tempColumn)
   .withColumn('newColumn1', col('existingColumn') + col('tempColumn'))
   .withColumn('newColumn2', col('existingColumn') - col('tempColumn'))
)

tempColumnDef = commonColumnExpression
df2 = (
   df.withColumn('tempColumn', tempColumn)
   .withColumn('newColumn1', col('existingColumn') + tempColumnDef)
   .withColumn('newColumn2', col('existingColumn') - tempColumnDef)
)

df1.explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Project [existingColumn#7L, 2 AS tempColumn#9, (existingColumn#7L + 2) AS newColumn1#12L, (existingColumn#7L - 2) AS newColumn2#16L]
# +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[existingColumn#7L]

df2.explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Project [existingColumn#7L, 2 AS tempColumn#21, (existingColumn#7L + 2) AS newColumn1#24L, (existingColumn#7L - 2) AS newColumn2#28L]
# +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[existingColumn#7L]
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether using the simplest case of a literal is representative/comprehensive.  Current implementation's heuristics may simply explicitly handle and optimize this case as exceptional.  Whether this conclusion holds up for more complicated cases or even in general is a whole other matter.  Speaking of generalizations, another aspect to consider is whether either approach a preferred design pattern that lends itself to future engine optimizations even if today's implementation may treat them identically.